# how to use the GetFileVersionInfo function?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, resources, versioning

I have this code - that is returning the file version (into a struct)
I'm using as example the shell32.dll 
but there are some values that I don't understand their meanings , and would love to get an explanation.

here is the code :

```
void GetFileVersion( PCHAR pFilePath  ,PVERSION pRetVersion)
{
DWORD               dwSize              = 0;
BYTE                *pVersionInfo       = NULL;
VS_FIXEDFILEINFO    *pFileInfo          = NULL;
UINT                pLenFileInfo        = 0;


/*getting the file version info size */
dwSize = GetFileVersionInfoSize( pFilePath, NULL );
if ( dwSize == 0 )
{
    printf( "Error in GetFileVersionInfoSize: %d\n", GetLastError() );
    return;
}

pVersionInfo = new BYTE[ dwSize ]; /*allocation of space for the verison size */

if ( !GetFileVersionInfo( pFilePath, 0, dwSize, pVersionInfo ) ) /*entering all info     data to pbVersionInfo*/
{
    printf( "Error in GetFileVersionInfo: %d\n", GetLastError() );
    delete[] pVersionInfo;
    return;
}

if ( !VerQueryValue( pVersionInfo, TEXT("\\"), (LPVOID*) &pFileInfo, &pLenFileInfo ) )
{
    printf( "Error in VerQueryValue: %d\n", GetLastError() );
    delete[] pVersionInfo;
    return;
}


/*checking if the allocation succeeded */
if (NULL == pRetVersion)
{
    printf("Allocation failed! \n" , GetLastError());
    return;
}


pRetVersion->major  =  ( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionMS >> 16 ) & 0xffff ;
pRetVersion->minor  =  ( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionMS) & 0xffff;
pRetVersion->hotfix =  ( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS >>  16 ) & 0xffff;
pRetVersion->other  =  ( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS) & 0xffff;      

}
```

1. what is the the meaning of dwSize ? is this only the file version size? where can I see it while clicking on the shell32.dll?
2. pLenFileinfo - what is this size ?
3. when I look at the struct of `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` there is only the version info information , Is there a wae to get for example : `File description` , `Date modified` , `Original filename` etc ? (all the other properties that are inside the "Details" )?

thanks !!!!!

Comment: It's described in the MSDN documentation. Please tell us what part of that you didn't understand.

Comment: I wrote it under the code - I don't understand the difference between the pLenInfoSize and dwSize , The version is 4 digits : 1.2.3.4 for example - so it's size should be like 7 characters : 28 bytes? no?

Comment: I think you need to read the documentation more carefully. For example, the version is stored in two DWORDs. It's not stored in text.

Comment: I've read it , that's why I'm using the last lines in my code and splitting the DWORDS to get a full version . buy when I debug it , I get that pLenFileInfo is 52 , and my current version is : 6.1.7601.17859 . and I don't understand the connection between them 2. also the deSize is 1860 - and I just don't understand where this number is comming from

Comment: ohhhhh Ok... I thought that getFileVersion is only connected to the version , and not to all the information. when I look at the 'VS_FIXEDFILEINFO' it doesn't have the "file description" field for example , it's also a part of the information , is there a way I can print it as well?

Comment: Use `VerQueryValue()` to access the rest of the version info that is not in the `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` struct.

Comment: Related question: Can 'GetFileVersionInfo' be used in a device driver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file version information is of variable length. It contains a number of different pieces of information. The total length of all these different pieces is given by the return value of `GetFileVersionInfoSize`.

When you call `VerQueryValue` you are asking for a specific individual piece of information within the overall version information. And the length of that specific part can never be larger that the overall size.

The documentation for [`VerQueryFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winver/nf-winver-verqueryvaluea) contains sample code that extracts the file description.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something - I get that dwSize is 1860 , and pLenFileInfo is 52. my version number is 6.1.7601.17869 . what is the connection between these numbers? when I look at the shell32.dll->details and see the version number - it's the only thing I know about the version , so I can't understand what are the meaning of the other numbers. Or the version is everything??? (file description , type , product name etc ??)

Comment: `pLenFileInfo` is 52 because it's a `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` which is 13 DWORDs. The return value of `GetFileVersionInfoSize` is larger, as I explained in my answer. Because it has more information in it. For example, the file description.