# How can I get a file version using a device driver?

Tags: windows, kernel, device-driver

I have a **device driver** that obtains the complete path to a binary eg:

```
  C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe
```

Is there a **kernel level** call that I can make similar to "GetFileVersionInfo" to obtain the product version of the binary?

OR can I just use:

[how to use the GetFileVersionInfo function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626295/how-to-use-the-getfileversioninfo-function)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research... it seems that 'GetFileVersionInfo' can be called from a device driver

see question 7 of 18 on http://www.osronline.com/showThread.cfm?link=59108

Here is the call for 'GetFileVersionInfo'

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003(v=vs.85).aspx
```

and

the call for 'GetFileVersionInfoSize'

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647005(v=vs.85).aspx
```